# Using delete[] on an array passed as an argument

Tags: c++, realloc

So let's say that you wanted to make a realloc function in C++. I imagine it can work something like this:

```
template<typename T>
void realloc(T** arr, int size, int original_size){
  T *newArr = new T[size];
  for(int i = 0; i<original_size;i++)
    newArr[i] = (*arr)[i];
  delete[] *arr;
  *arr = newArr;
}
```

Now my question is wheter it is correct to use `delete[]` here? From what I know allocated memory size is tracked at runtime so C++ knows how much to delete. Is that preserved when passing it like this or are there better ways of doing this?

Comment: There is no garbage collector in C++

Comment: Damn for some reason I thought there was. I'll edit the question

Comment: The code looks fine. Of course you get something like this for free (and with a superior implementation) if you use `std::vector`.

Comment: The *only* time it is acceptable to use `delete [] *arr` is if `*arr` is a pointer that results from a `new []` expression (or null, for which `delete []` has no effect).   If  the caller passes an argument such that `*arr` is not the result of such an expression, the behaviour is undefined.    Also, in your code, if `original_size` exceeds the actual size allocated for `*arr` or if `original_size > size`, the behaviour of your loop is undefined (accessing past the end of allocated memory).    In the end, you would be better off using a `std::vector` - which takes care of resizing cleanly.

Comment: Using smart pointers or containers would save lots of effort than manually handling memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is wheter it is correct to use delete[] here?

Yes, as long as `*arr` was allocated using `new[]`.

> From what I know allocated memory size is tracked at runtime so C++ knows how much to delete. Is that preserved when passing it like this [...]?

I'm not really sure what you mean here. The runtime keeps track of memory allocations, yes. But you have to be explicit about using `delete[]` for arrays (like `new int[10])` and `delete` for non-arrays (like `new MyClass()`).

> or are there better ways of doing this?

Using raw pointers should be avoided, even naked `new` is considered bad practice these days. Smart pointers and STL-containers like `std::vector` are superior alternatives for almost every scenario.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean the compiler. Made a mistake when writing. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @Buffer yep, fixed the quote :)

Comment: FYI it's "these days" :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Ahh, thanks. I'm no native english speaker :) But it seems like there's actually a difference between the two.

Comment: The difference between "these" and "those" is distance (by some measure) from the speaker.   So "these days"  refers literally to "a time interval or set of days that includes today"  whereas "those days" refers to "a time interval or set of days that excludes today".